# How do I destroy my multimeters?

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter, fuses

During a task that involves current measurement in the mA and µA range, I managed to blow up the fuses of 3 DMMs. The DMMs were an old Voltcraft DMM from the 1990's, a PeakTech 2025 (similar to the [2025A](https://www.peaktech.de/uk/PeakTech-P-2025-A-True-RMS-1000-V-digital-multimeter-6000-Counts-USB/P-2025-A)) and a Voltcraft [VC175 [German]](https://www.conrad.de/de/p/voltcraft-vc175-hand-multimeter-digital-cat-iii-600-v-anzeige-counts-4000-124457.html), all in the range below 100€. In all 3 cases it was the lower current fuse (500 mA/600 mA/2 A), not the high current fuse (10 A). I have bought a bunch of new fuses and replaced them, that's not a big deal.

However, I'd like to figure out why and how the fuses blew up in all 3 DMMs. And maybe, just for fun, do that again for demonstration purposes and the sake of learning [as suggested in this similar case](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18390/fuse-blowing-in-12-multimeters-rated-for-200ma-only-measuring-12-5ma-why).

This was the measuring task, calculating ß of a transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7cB0L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's what I believe could help:

- the DMM was already connected to the circuit, but turned off initially
- I turned on (and output) the power supply before I turned on the DMM
- the power supply is a 5 A supply. I usually work with an 1 A limit (still enough to blow a 600 mA fuse, though) and I'll lower that next time
- I usually work with 12 and 5 V. I doubt it could have been set to 30 V (maximum).
- in order to get to a reasonable setting on the DMM like mA, I need to turn the switch through a bunch of other positions like R and µA. This may vary per instrument
- because I was measuring ohms before, the red cable might have been in the wrong socket (like V instead of mA), but certainly not in the 10 A socket.
- some of the DMMs have an auto power-off, and in order to turn it on again, I turn the switch back to OFF and then on again
- The potentiometer R may have had extreme values like 0 Ohm or 10 kOhm
- Other than that, I'm pretty confident that the connections of the components were ok. It was reviewed.

Well, you might say: why don't you just repeat the experiment and see in which position the fuse blows? Answers: a) The fuses are not easily regardable but hidden inside the DMM housing. I would need to check after each position. b) They are no longer simple wires in glass. They are filled with white material.

My question is: **given the assumption that the wiring was according the diagram, just the socket at the instrument might have been the wrong one, which DMM switch position would blow up the fuse?** As I don't see a short circuit path in the diagram, could the voltage of the internal batteries of the DMM have blown the fuse?

If you like, maybe you can add a few best practices for working in a circuit with DMMs that turn off. Should I always disconnect the cables while I turn the switch? Sounds like much overhead.

Comment: Resistance mode is a good suspect because it causes the multimeter to supply power to the circuit from its battery. Although the maximum current should still be too low to blow any fuses. The cable being in the wrong socket can also be a problem.... except that the maximum current should still be too low to blow any fuses! It should be hard to blow a 200mA fuse with 1000 ohms in series!

Comment: If you connected them as per the diagram, fuses can't burn. Are you sure you connected like in your diagram? I think that is the false assumption.

Comment: @user253751: that's what confuses me as well

Comment: @Justme: thanks. Still possible, even with the review.

Comment: Did you check your resistors? Maybe it is a lot lower value?

Comment: I agree with @VladimirDjuricic, double check the values of R1 and R2. Also, make sure your meters are not measuring cross a resistor but actually inserted in the circuit between two components. You can also eliminate the ammeters and use a volt meter to measure across R1 and R2. Then divide the voltage you measured by the resistor size to get AMPs. A much safer method that will not blow fuses.

Comment: Are you sure *you* blew the fuses with *this* measurement? If you still have it set up you could try with the 10A current scale and poke around with a voltmeter.

Comment: @GTElectronics: that's definitely a great suggestion

Comment: Both those multimeters have a *horrible* rotary selector switch. You must pass through the **most sensitive** current scale to get to **less-sensitive** current scale. Proper technique selects highest current range first, then probe for a measurement. However, doing otherwise is merely abuse, not likely fuse-blowing.

Comment: Burning 3 fuses probably means you connected meters in parallel, not series.  Turn on dmm, select scale you want, then turn on power supply.